# For loop not working in nested Streambuilder [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, for-loop

I am using nested Streambuilder to first get the memberId of a task and then The MemberDetails. However the for loop seems to be not working, as the code is only being executed once, instead of as many times as there are tasks

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: taskDetailsStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      for (var taskDoc in snapshot.data!.docs) {
        Map<String, dynamic> taskData =
            taskDoc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

        String memberId = taskData['memberId'];
        print('activated: $memberId');

        return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('members')
              .doc(memberId)
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, memberSnapshot) {
            if (!memberSnapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            Map<String, dynamic>? memberData = memberSnapshot.data?.data();
            print("activated: ${memberData!['name']}");

            String pickUpDate = taskData['pickupDate'] ?? '';
            String dropOffDate = taskData['dropoffDate'] ?? '';

            DateTime? dtpickUpDate = pickUpDate.isNotEmpty
                ? DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(pickUpDate)
                : null;
            DateTime? dtdropOffDate = dropOffDate.isNotEmpty
                ? DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').parse(dropOffDate)
                : null;

            TaskDetails task = TaskDetails(
              // Task Details
              taskType: taskData['taskType'],
              pickupDate: pickUpDate,
              dropoffDate: dropOffDate,
              dtDropoffDate: dtdropOffDate,
              dtPickupDate: dtpickUpDate,
              notes: taskData['notes'] ?? 'No notes',
              pickupTime: taskData['pickupTime'] ?? 'No time',
              dropoffTime: taskData['dropoffTime'] ?? 'No time',
              taskId: taskDoc.id ?? 'No id',
              pickupCompletedAt: null,
              dropoffCompletedAt: null,

              // Member Details
              memberName: memberData!['name'] ?? 'No member name',
              memberId: memberSnapshot.data!.id ?? 'No member id',
              address: memberData['address'] ?? 'No address',
              society: memberData['society'] ?? 'No society',
              phoneNumber: memberData['phoneNumber'] ?? 'No phone number',
            );
```

For loop not being executed. Both Streambuilder only retrieving data for one Task and Member

Comment: Of course it will only execute the first iteration because you return something inside it. Please explain what you're actually trying to achieve.